# react-router html5 video re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, react-router

i have a React Video Component which renders:

```
<video autoPlay loop poster={this.props.poster}>
    <source src={this.props.video} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

as a child of my routes Components:

```
var Login = require('./containers/Login/Login.jsx');
var ForgotPassword = require('./containers/Login/ForgotPassword.jsx');

[
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />,
    <Route path="/login/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword}/>
]
```

when changing routes the Video Component re-renders and i see the reload flash on the browser, along with the video restarting.
is there any way to avoid from re-rendering the Video Component while routing?

i managed to make it work by using the same component in both routes,
and making UI changes by reference to the url.

i lose the component events with this work around (componentWillUnmount, componentWillMount etc.)

will appreciate any help,
thanks

Comment: possible you are looking for _shouldComponentUpdate_ method [_**Link is here**_](http://buildwithreact.com/article/optimizing-with-shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: having a hard time figuring out es6 synax for * shouldComponentUpdate*... will appreciate your help

Comment: i've added an answer you can look through it.

Answer (score 2):

As i told in your case you can try to use *shouldComponentUpdate* method, but i'm not sure about routing and how it works with routing.
It takes two arguments *nextProps & nextState* and returns **true or false** depending on your logic, and if it true then your component will be re-rendered otherwise won't.
So here is an example:

```
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log('Should Component Update');
        return nextState.count % 5 === 0
    }
```

In this case it renders only when state is divide by 5. Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/120/) also i've used ES6 syntax.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: i should add this function to the VideoComponent class, right?
anyway, tried it with no luck. a jsfiddle example by any saviour would be great :D

Answer (score 0):

When the states(or props) are changed, React components always re-render without Implementing the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) or using [PreRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html).

If you have some re-render condition Implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` else use the `PreRenderMixin` simply.

Try it, and share your result. thanks

Comment: i tired both methods with no luck. also tried gaearon/react-pure-render. can you please direct me to an implementation of the *shouldComponentUpdate* with es6?